# R apply a function using endsWith to a vector

Tags: r

I need to apply a function (which takes two arguments of different lengths) to each item in a vector. The function looks up the value in the first argument that ends with the characters in the second argument and outputs the index (the objective is to perform a left join on two tables using a fuzzy join, but regex_left_join crashed so this is the first step in a workaround solution).

Example input:

```
    x <- c("492820UA665110", "492820UA742008", "493600N077751", "671884RB25355")
    y <- c("RB25355", "S56890")
```

Function:

```
    idx_endsWith <- function(.x, .y) {
       return(ifelse(length(which(endsWith(.x, .y))) == 1,
              which(endsWith(.x, .y)),
              NA))
     }
```

So for example,

```
> idx_endsWith(x, y[1])
[1] 4
```

How can I apply this function to each element in y without using a loop? I need to vectorize the function, but mapply doesn't work because the vectors need to be the same length. I'm looking for a solution in dplyr.

Comment: It would help if you specify how far back into the string it should look back...for instance, if you look back by 6 characters, `B25355`, no matches in `x` are TRUE. That is, should a match of 1 character suffice? 2, 3, 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `dplyr`, as you requested, this should work:

```
data.frame(y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(index = idx_endsWith(x, y))
```